# Why can't I use push_back function?

Tags: c++, stdvector, push-back

```
void Add(vector< vector<string> > &name,
         vector< vector<string> > &author,
         vector< vector<string> > &pub,
         int &total_books)
{
    Line();
    string book_name,book_author,book_pub;

    cout << "Please enter the book name: ";
    cin >> book_name;
    cout << "Please enter the author name: ";
    cin >> book_author;
    cout << "Please enter the publisher name: ";
    cin >> book_pub;

    name.push_back(book_name);
    author.push_back(book_author);
    pub.push_back(book_pub);

    ++total_books;

    cout << "The book has been successfully added.";
}
```

Compiler says this:

```
[Error] no matching function for call to
 'std::vector<std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >>::push_back(std::string&)'**
```

Does anybody know what's the problem?

Comment: Line() is another fuinction to print out division line;;

Comment: What's unclear about the error? You are trying to `push_back` a `string` into a `vector` holding `vector<string>`.

Comment: why is `name` a `vector<vector<string> >` instead of a `std::vector<std::string>` ?

Comment: I think the downvotes here are a little harsh.  The code and error message are in good format; and the issue perfectly clear.  While it might be a fairly trivial question, I wouldn't go as far to say that it's "not helpful".  Compiler error messages can certainly be cryptic; especially with templates; and for non-native English speakers I can only imagine the pain.

Answer (score 4):

With a `std::vector<std::vector<string> >`, you need to `push_back` an instance of `std::vector<string>`.

Example:

```
std::vector<string> many_strings;
std::vector<std::vector<string> > matrix_of_strings;

many_strings.push_back("Sid");
many_strings.push_back("Alice");
many_strings.push_back("Bob");

matrix_of_strings.push_back(many_strings);
```

In your case, a better solution is to make a structure with the fields rather than using *parallel vectors*.

```
struct Book
{
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
    std::string publisher;
};
```

You can then add an input function:

```
struct Book
{
     //...
     void input_from_user();
};
void Book::input_from_user()
{
    std::cout << "Enter book title: ";
    std::getline(title);
    std::cout << "Enter book author: ";
    std::getline(author);
    std::cout << "Enter book publisher: ";
    std::getinle(publisher);
}
```

Your input process could look like this:

```
Book b;
b.input_from_user();
```

Your database would look like this:

```
std::vector<Book> database;
database.push_back(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are vectors of vectors (`vector<vector<string> > &name`), which seems to be one level to deep - you cannot `push_back` a `string` into those, but only a vector of strings.

What are you trying to accomplish with this? Why not simply use `vector<string> &name`, which should work just fine?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you're trying to push a string into a vector of vectors.

First, why are those vectors two-storeyed? If you change them into `vector<string>` no other changes will be needed (in this fragment.)

```
void Add(vector<string> &name, vector<string> &author, vector<string> &pub);
```

Next, if, due to some reason you still need them to be double level, well, you can insert fresh strings as singletons:

```
name.push_back({book_name});
```

(may need more verbosity in older standard:

```
author.push_back(vector<string>(1, book_author));
```

or add them to vector's most recent element:

```
pub.back().push_back(book_pub);
```

Perhaps, in the latter case you first need to check if the large vector is not empty, so there's a `back()`.

It is unclear from your snippet what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was being so stupid;;